# How to filter multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 columns in my table. C1 and C2. I want to select data out from that table provided if

```
C1 not 3 and C2 not 5  
OR   
C1 not 5 nad C2 not 3
```

Below is my sql statement

```
select * from table A
where ((C1 <> 3 and C2 <> 5) AND (C1 <> 5 and C2 <> 3))
```

The above successfully filtered out most cases. But it failed to select out some data e.g.
C1 = 5 and C2 = 7
I have attached a print screen for better elaboration.[image]

Comment: Your code has a different condition than your description.

Comment: `select * from table A
where ((C1 <> 3 and C2 <> 5) OR (C1 <> 5 and C2 <> 3))`

Comment: The C1 = 5 and C2 = 7 is just an example. Based on the where condition, i should be able to select out the 5 and 7. But the data is not returned due to the where condition has filtered it out.

Comment: That is confusing. Please add example data and expected output.

Comment: i have updated the issue with a print screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `and` everywhere, that means your query
`select * from table A
where ((C1 <> 3 and C2 <> 5) AND (C1 <> 5 and C2 <> 3))`

is the same as

`select * from table A
where C1 <> 3 and C2 <> 5 AND C1 <> 5 and C2 <> 3`

So, the correct will be

`select * from table A
where not (C1 = 3 and C2 = 5) AND not (C1 = 5 and C2 = 3)`

Comment: I have tried all, but none is able to return me the good data. Updated my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Trying using **`OR`** in between the two **`AND`** conditions:

```
select * from table A
where C1 <> 3 AND C2 <> 5 AND C1 <> 5 AND C2 <> 3
```

Comment: I had tried using OR. It returned the case 5,7 but it also returned 3,5 and 5,3

Comment: Try uisng `select * from table A
where C1 <> 3 AND C2 <> 5 and C1 <> 5 AND C2 <> 3`

Comment: Try without any brackets.. This would solve your issue.

Comment: same. 5,7 is not appearing even though i take out the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `CASE`

```
 select * from tableA
where (case when C1=3 OR C2=5 then 0
            when C1=5 OR C2=3 then 0
            else 1
      end)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

will it work,

```
select * from table A
where C1 not in(3,5) and C2  not in(3,5)
```